# Pointer comparison warning

Tags: c, pointers, warnings

I'm making a 16bit checksum of all words in a memory space from 0 to 0x0020000 with:

```
uint16_t checksum = 0;
    for (uint16_t * word_val = 0; word_val < 0x0020000ul; word_val++)
    {
        checksum += *word_val;
    }
```

I receive the warning "comparison between pointer and integer". How can I make this warning go away?

Comment: Seems you are trying to access memory that may not be available to you. Doesn't look healthy to me....

Comment: @Kay,  Note the `l` in `0x0020000ul` serves no useful purpose here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word_val` is a pointer, `0x0020000ul` is an integer, and comparing them leads to a warning.

To prevent this warning, just cast the integer constant to a uint16_t pointer, in order to compare datas of the same type :

```
uint16_t checksum = 0;
for (uint16_t * word_val = 0; word_val < (uint16_t *)0x0020000ul; word_val++)
{
    checksum += *word_val;
}
```